# Laravel Redirect Back Issues

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8.0 to create a web application. I have multiple pages that can only be seen if you are signed into an account. I have it setup so that once you go to the page, it uses a controller function to return the view, but before that it checks if you are logged in with a simple if statement. If you are logged in, it returns the view, else it redirects to login page. I am wanting to make it so after they login it redirects them back to the page they were trying to go before. I used `return redirect()->back();` to do this, but it returns them too the login page as it thinks that is where it was before. I use a separate route and controller function to login them in via the form. If anyone could help, I would much appreciate it!

Comment: A middleware is best used for auth checks, laravel ships with `auth` middleware that redirects to login page if someone tries to visit a page that requires prior login and that user is not logged in. Also you may use the `intended` method of the Redirect class which redirects to the intended URL before redirecting to the login page. Head to the docs to better understand these topics.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use following code. In your `login` function just add this

```
Session::put('previousUrl',url()->previous());
$previous_url = Session::get('previousUrl');
```

And after login authentication successful just call this

```
return Session::get('previousUrl');
```

Answer (score 0):

i prefer use this

> redirect()->route('your route name')

because in logic, after submit form, it goes to another route which is */login* with **POST Request**

So when u use this

> redirect()->back()

it goes to */login* with **GET Request** which is your login form